# Dynamic Value in json array using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So I have an empty array defined.

```
admin.links = [];
```

I then push items to it like so.

```
angular.forEach(links, function(value, key) {

                var title = value.title;
                var url = value.url;

                admin.links.counter.push({
                    'parent' : counter,
                    'name' : title,
                    'url' : url
                })

            })
```

When I run the code above I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

`counter` is a dynamic value. How would I do this?

I want it to be something like admin.links.0

Answer (score 0):

What you mean with:

> counter is a dynamic value.

`admin.links`is an array, so if you want to add items you must use:

```
admin.links.push
```

if, instead, you want links to be an object you should initialize it with:

```
admin.links = {
  counter: []
}

admin.links.counter.push()
```